# Error while upload file to sharepoint using python

Tags: python, office365-rest-client

Here is the python code I am trying to use to upload csv file from local to sharepoint. Can you please help with error message?

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.runtime.utilities.request_options import RequestOptions

app_settings = {
    'url': 'https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/ProjectName'
    'client_id': '4f510936',
    'client_secret': 'C9'
 }

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url=app_settings['url'])



if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_app(client_id=app_settings['client_id'], client_secret=app_settings['client_secret']):
    

    path = r"C:\Users\Test.csv"
    with open(path, 'rb') as content_file:
        file_content = content_file.read()

    list_title = "My Folder/Azure"
    target_folder = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title(list_title).rootFolder
    
    name = os.path.basename(path)
    print(target_folder,name)
    target_file = target_folder.upload_file(name, file_content)
    ctx.execute_query()
    print("File url: {0}".format(target_file.serverRelativeUrl))
```

I would like to upload the file to "Azure" folder under "My Folder"
My Sharepoint location: https :// contonso .sharepoint.com/sites/ProjectName/My%20Folder/Forms/AllItems.aspx and sub folder is>>Azure

> **Error Message**:
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> 21     name = os.path.basename(path)
> 22     print(target_folder,name)
> ---> 23     target_file = target_folder.upload_file(name, file_content)
> 24     ctx.execute_query()
> 25     print("File url: {0}".format(target_file.serverRelativeUrl))AttributeError: 'Folder' object has no attribute 'upload_file'

**Log from module installation:**

> Processing c:\users\user_id\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\a9\22\30\e7dfb5f53fe2ad180c4c789945bf1320804c75a31ffc79cf59\office365_rest_python_client-2.1.7.post1-cp37-none-any.whl
> Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\user_id\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Office365-REST-Python-Client) (2.24.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: adal in c:\users\user_id\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Office365-REST-Python-Client) (1.2.2)
> Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\user_id\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->Office365-REST-Python-Client) (1.25.9)
> Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\user_id\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->Office365-REST-Python-Client) (2020.6.20)
> Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\user_id\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->Office365-REST-Python-Client) (3.0.4)
> Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\user_id\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->Office365-REST-Python-Client) (2.10)
> Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1.0 in c:\users\user_id\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from adal->Office365-REST-Python-Client) (2.8.1)
> Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=1.1.0 in c:\users\user_id\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from adal->Office365-REST-Python-Client) (2.9.2)
> Requirement already satisfied: PyJWT>=1.0.0 in c:\users\user_id\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from adal->Office365-REST-Python-Client) (1.7.1)
> Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\user_id\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.1.0->adal->Office365-REST-Python-Client) (1.15.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8 in c:\users\user_id\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=1.1.0->adal->Office365-REST-Python-Client) (1.14.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\user_id\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8->cryptography>=1.1.0->adal->Office365-REST-Python-Client) (2.20)
> Installing collected packages: Office365-REST-Python-Client
> Successfully installed Office365-REST-Python-Client-2.1.7.post1

Comment: target_folder is a string, not the context object.

Comment: @ewong here is reference code and looks like it is object: https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/examples/sharepoint/upload_file.py

Comment: My bad.  Sorry I seemed to have mis-processed that error.  That said, there seems to be some disconnect between the github.com's office365/sharepoint/folders/folder.py code and how you're system's setup.   Is your python's office365 reset module updated?

Comment: What I mean is in your office365 rest python module in lib/site-packages, in office365/sharepoint/folders/folder.py, does it have upload_file()?   Have you tried updating the office365 module?

Comment: Thanks for your responses @ewong, folder.py is available on sharepoint folder.. I dont have "folders" on my location "AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\office365\sharepoint.folder.py"

Comment: Yes I have updated module from my notebook..   pip install Office365-REST-Python-Client.. Also I noticed .. there is no upload_file method on this folder.py file.. :(

Comment: I have tried re-installing the modules.. but still don't see upload_file() method in folder.py. Updated question with log from pip installation..